# How i can capture the screen with an image that loaded from server using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

How I can capture the screen with an image that loaded from the server using angular. Now I can capture the screen with only text data that load from the back-end, But the image is missed.

Note: I can load the text and image from the backend. But this code can't capture the image

This is the HTML Code

```
<div #screen id="cards">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class=" col-12 col-md-6 box mt-4">
<img class="img-layer" src="{{url}}/xxxx/xxxx/{{xxxxx}}/xxxx/front.jpg" style="height: 100%; width: 
100%; border: 1px solid black;">
<div class="row  justify-content-center avatar">
<div class="col-md-8 text-center d-flex">
<img src="{{url}}/xxxxx/profile/{{xxxxxxx}}/student/{{xxxxxx}}.jpg" style="height: 200px; width: 
200px; border-radius: 5px;">
</div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-7 clg-details space">{{aaaa}}</div>
<div class="row">{{aaaa}}</div>
<div class="row">{{aaa}}</div>
<div class="row">{{aaaa}}</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="download">
<img #canvas>
<a #downloadLink></a> 
</div>
```

This is the TS Code

```
@ViewChild('screen', { static: false }) screen: ElementRef; 
@ViewChild('canvas', { static: false }) canvas: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('downloadLink', { static: false }) downloadLink: ElementRef;

captureImage() {
console.log((this.screen.nativeElement));
html2canvas(this.screen.nativeElement).then(canvas => {
this.canvas.nativeElement.src = canvas.toDataURL();
this.downloadLink.nativeElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
this.downloadLink.nativeElement.download = 'id-card.png';
this.downloadLink.nativeElement.click();
}); 
}
```

[This is the image what I need after render and save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAyec.jpg)

[This is the image that I get. note that background image is missed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zIQM.png)

Comment: This code worked in production server

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create an img [src]'s value in the front end. 
e.g.`<img [src]="myImage">`in your HTML.

In component :

```
 myImage : any;
     createImage(image : blob){
     let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.addEventListener("load" => {
     this.myImage = reader.result;
}, false);
if(image){
 reader.readAsDataURL(image);
}
}
```

assuming you are getting blob from backend.